# How to create Nested Contraints?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

Consider the following xml:

```
<Record>
   <Author>
      <FirstName>David</FirstName>
      <LastName>Raj</LastName>
   </Author>
   <Author>
      <FirstName>Sim</FirstName>
      <LastName>Son</LastName>
   </Author>
   <Editor>
      <FirstName>Sandy</FirstName>
      <LastName>John<LastName>
   </Editor>
</Record>
```

In present I use `element-query` to get the values from `<Author>`.

```
<constraint name="Author">
    <element-query ns="" name="Author" />
    {$OPTIONS}
</constraint>
```

I don't want to search or get the values of `<LastName>` element, but need only the value of `<FirstName>` of Author element alone. Is it possible to create **nested-constraint** for this??
If possible could anyone elaborate it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sofi:

You supply the criteria for the contained element in the query, not in the constraint.

In this case, you would create two constraints:  an `element-query` constraint on the ContentOwnerType and a value constraint on the Description. Then, in the query, the `element-constraint-query` for ContentOwnerType should contain the `value-constraint-query` on the Description.

Here's the documentation for `element-constraint-query`:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_64263

As an alternative, you can define a field that includes ContentOwnerType and excludes Code:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_78911

Answer (score 0):

If we need to show only FirstName

we can create constraint Author referring to

FirstName (for this we need index created on FirstName)

```
<search:constraint name="Author">
  <search:range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation" type="xs:string" facet="true">
     <search:facet-option>ascending</search:facet-option>
     <search:element ns="" name="FirstName"/>
  </search:range>
</search:constraint>
```

Or

We can have a path index for Author/FirstName to ensure FirstName is under Author only.

```
<search:constraint name="Author">
   <search:range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation" type="xs:string" facet="true">
      <search:facet-option>ascending</search:facet-option>
       <search:path-index>*:Author/*:FirstName</search:path-index>
   </search:range>
</search:constraint>
```

Hope this helps :)